# Run delete.bat on a specific date

Tags: windows

Hi how can I add here a specific run date for this script without using task scheduler.

forfiles /p "C:\user\cim\documents" /m *.docs* /c "cmd /c del @path"

Comment: You can't run a script at a specific date/time without having some external app monitoring the clock and then running the script at the designated time. Why don't you want to use Task Scheduler? It is designed for exactly this kind of operation.

Comment: I just want to run it silently without configuration on task scheduler

Comment: You do know that Task Scheduler can be accessed in code, and set to run scripts silently, don't you? Give your script an optional parameter that will setup the scheduled task when the script is run with that parameter. If the script is run without that parameter, do your main work instead

Comment: @RemyLebeau can you help me on how to access it using code?

Comment: can you give me a sample

Comment: i dont have idea on how to access it using codes

Comment: Have you read the [Task Scheduler documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/task-scheduler-start-page) yet?

Comment: nope, and i dont have an idea about this

Comment: Then I suggest you start reading, it tells you exactly what you need to do, and includes examples, for instance [Time Trigger Example (Scripting)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/time-trigger-example--scripting-).

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to make sure a program is launched at a certain moment:

- Add it in the task scheduler
- Run the program constantly, starting with a `While Now!=desired_moment()`

The latter is what you are looking for, but you do have the drawback that your program must be running while doing nothing.

For your information: in Windows: `Now` (as in date of today) can be shown using `Date /T`.